# How to solve $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2k-1)(2k+1)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, telescopic-series

Can you help me please with this sum?

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2k-1)(2k+1)}$$

I have no idea how to solve it. Result is $\frac{1}{2}$.

Thank you

Comment: This is a [telescoping series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series).

Comment: I would have expected the answer to be closer to $\frac{\pi^2}{24}\approx .411$. Curious...

Comment: Aha. Most of the difference is in the difference of the first terms: $\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}\approx .083$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for nth partial sum we have:
$s_n := \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{(2k-1)(2k+1)} = \frac12 
\sum_{k=1}^{n}  \left(\frac1{2k-1}-\frac1{2k+1}\right) = \frac12 \cdot ( 1 - \frac{1}{2n+1})$
Solving the limit:
$ \lim_{n \to \infty } s_n =  \lim_{n \to \infty } ( \frac12 \cdot ( 1 - \frac{1}{2n+1}) ) = \frac12 = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2k-1)(2k+1)}$

Thanks for the hint :)

Answer (score 7):

**Hint:**
$$\frac1{(2k-1)(2k+1)}=\frac12\left(\frac1{2k-1}-\frac1{2k+1}\right)$$

Comment: You were faster than me. +1

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**
Expand the numerator as such
$$1 = \frac12(2k+1 - (2k - 1))$$
And use telescoping series.